# Error with Bilinear interpolation implementation

Tags: c++, opencv

My project goal is to implement own function for Bilinear interpolation after Affine transformation. As I am beginner I could not find solution to locate the non integer coordinates after the image transformation, So I did like following. It is showing error after the execution as

> cannot convert 'x' (type 'double*') to type 'cv::Point'

```
int main()
{
    double value =0.0 ;
    double i,j;
    const cv::Mat img = cv::imread("/media/sf_vbox_share/ubuntushare/chess2.jpg",CV_8U);    
    Mat imgAffine;
    Mat par(2, 3, CV_64FC1);   

    imgAffine = Mat::zeros( img.rows, img.cols,CV_32FC1);    
    par.at<double>(0,0)=   1;  //p1
    par.at<double>(1,0)=  0.02  ;  //p2;
    par.at<double>(0,1)= -0.03 ; //p3;
    par.at<double>(1,1)= 1 ;  //p4;
    par.at<double>(0,2)= -0.001 ;   //p5;
    par.at<double>(1,2)= -0.005;//p6;
    warpAffine(img,imgAffine,par, img.size());

    namedWindow("image",WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("image",imgAffine); 

    //for locating non integer coordinates..     
    for(i=0.0;i< imgAffine.rows ; i += 0.1)
    {
        for(j=0.0;j< imgAffine.cols; j+= 0.1) 
        {
            Bil_interp(imgAffine,&i,&j,&value);
        }
    }

    imshow("interpol img",imgAffine);    
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}

void Bil_interp(const Mat& image, double* x, double* y, double* val)
{    
    int x1 = cvFloor(x);int y1 = cvFloor(y);
    int x2 = x1+1;int y2 = y1+1;
    double q11,q12,q21, q22;    
    q11 = (image.at<double>(x1,y1));
    q21 = (image.at<double>(x2,y1));
    q12 = (image.at<double>(x1,y2));
    q22 = (image.at<double>(x2,y2));

    val = ((1/( (x2-x1)*(y2-y1) ) ) *(q11*(x2-x)*(y2-y)+q21*(x2-x1)*(y2-
           y) +q12*(x2-x)*(y-y1)+q22*(x-x1)*(y-y1)));

    image.at<double>(x,y) = val;      
}
```

I really do not know how to use `cv::Point` in the code. And I am not allowed to use interpolation flag in `warpAffine` function. 
I could not find or understand any post or article. 
Can anyone suggest me how to solve the problem here? How exactly we could know there are non integer coordinates?

Comment: Wow, that's some creative indentation there.

Comment: Might help to know which line generates the error.  It looks like `cvFloor()` takes double, not pointer to double.  `image.at<double>(x,y) = val;` also looks like it wouldn't expect pointers.

Comment: @ebyrob. okay. Apart from that for retrieving the values of non-integer coordinates. That logic would work??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many syntactic errors in this piece of code. First of all, you're using pointers for `x`, `y` and `val` and you don't dereference them, but pass them by value to functions like `cvFloor()` and `Mat::at()` as if they were local variables - this cannot work and every call to these functions right now will give you a conversion error during compilation.

The same goes for this line:

```
val = ((1/( (x2-x1)*(y2-y1) ) ) *(q11*(x2-x)*(y2-y)+q21*(x2-x1)*(y2-
       y) +q12*(x2-x)*(y-y1)+q22*(x-x1)*(y-y1)));
```

you're passing pointers by value and try to subtract pointers (x and y) from local variables (x2, y2 etc.).

BTW there's no reason for making x, y, and val pointers. In fact, that doesn't make sense.

There are other, ***multiple*** bugs:

For example, `Bil_interp()` takes a const reference to Mat object as an argument, and you try to modify this object inside the function - another compilation error.

The call to `warpAffine()` will trigger runtime error as `img` and `imgAffine` don't have the same type (one is `CV_8U`, and the other one is `CV_32`).

`image.at<double>()` in `Bil_interp()` is also going to crash your program at runtime, because image passed to the function is `CV_32FC1`, whereas double corresponds to `CV_64FC1`.

---

You should really start by learning basic C++, because you clearly have no idea what you are doing, both in terms of how you use C++, but also regarding the way you use openCV. This code looks like random things pasted together. I don't write it to offend you - it's just with your current knowledge you are going to keep getting stuck all the time as you are not able to write a few lines of code that would compile.

Comment: Consider rephrasing your last paragraph. It's very clear the OP does not know enough C++ and lacks some basic understanding on how to effectively use `cv::Mat` and that's why they're here, but you can be a bit gentler with your point.

Comment: @KjMag. Thank you for the clarification. Basically I am not from software department, but started coding very recently, I do not have much time and need to learn lot at a time. I will correct my mistakes soon. It is okay Mr Rayryeng. Thank you.

Comment: @rayryeng Probably you're right, the last one turned out to be a bit harsh, but the OP has already read it, so I guess there's no point editing it anymore.

Comment: @rayryeng the words may seem harsh, but I think a couple harsh words are a lot nicer than drive-by down voting the question with no constructive criticism.  I think it goes without saying that padoala priyanka is very smart to have gotten this confused this quickly.